# jQuery beginner: how to add css transition when using toggleClass("open")?

Tags: jquery, css, transition

I have made a beginner's attempt at making a vertical navigation menu of which the parents open on hover:

**HTML**

```
<ul class="pages-list">
   <li class="page_item">Grand Parent 1
      <ul class="first-children">
         <li class="page_item">Parent 1</li>
         <li class="page_item">Parent 2 (hover me)
            <ul class="children">
               <li class="page_item">Child 1</li>
               <li class="page_item">Child 2
                  <ul class="children">
                      <li class="page_item">Grandchild 1</li>
                      <li class="page_item">Grandchild 2</li>
                      <li class="page_item">Grandchild 3</li>
                 </ul>
              </li>
               <li class="page_item">Child 3</li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li class="page_item">Parent 3 (hover me)
            <ul class="children">
               <li class="page_item">Child 1</li>
               <li class="page_item">Child 2</li>
               <li class="page_item">Child 3</li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li class="page_item">Parent 4</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.first-children > .page_item > .children.open {
    height:auto;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: height 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: height 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
.first-children > .page_item > .children {
    height: 0;
    overflow:hidden;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: height 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: height 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

(tried the transition on both all and height)

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".first-children > .page_item").hover(function(){
    $(this).find("> .children").toggleClass("open");
  });
});
```

**Result**
http://jsfiddle.net/senlin/DVUZ5/

Now what I would like to have is to use a CSS transition when the children receive the class open

Is that even possible with height:0 and height: auto?

If not how do I need to alter the code so the transition effect becomes possible? I tried it on both "all" and "height", but that doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can not transition `height` between `0` and `auto`, but you can transition the `max-height`-property between 0 and some fixed value.

I have updated your fiddle to show an example: http://jsfiddle.net/ydXs9/2/

This solution is obviously not ideal, but if your menu items are roughly equal in height you can get nice results in this way.

If your sub-menus vary greatly in height, you are probably better off using [jQuery.animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

Comment: thanks @tobi I will try it with max-height. I had a look at the animate function, but I don't think I can figure that out in my context.